# How to return a proper data type without warnings

Tags: c, linked-list, return

I'm trying to build my own linked list data structure and I'm getting trouble with one thing: I have no idea in returning a struct data type which works as NULL with pointer.
For example:

```
item pophead(node *list)
{
    head = list;
    node *newlist = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node*));
    item result;
    if(!list)
    {
        perror("There is nothing to be pop\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        newlist = list->next;
        result = list->data;
        free(list);
        list = newlist;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is my program to pop an item from the top of the linked list. The problem is at the first case to check if the list is empty so I want my prgram to return nothing but when I write like this, it gets a warning message.

I want to add that `item` here is a structure data type, not a single data type like `int` or `char`.

Comment: Wrong allocation size.  Avoid that mistake with `node *newlist =  malloc(sizeof *newlist);`

Comment: Why do you need to `malloc` more memory in order to remove the head element from the list?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Don't say it wrong because my compiler do not show any error messages. Maybe that is your habit to do it, though

Comment: Just because your compiler can't detect an error doesn't mean your code is correct. The version posted by chux is the correct one, yours doesn't allocate enough memory.

Comment: @FelixG You're wrong because if I were wrong, when I print out all items in my list, it would get wrong. Instead, you should show me some pages or website that show my source code is wrong

Comment: @HoangNam It's simple, really... you allocate `sizeof(node*)` which is the size of a "pointer to node", if your `node` type is bigger than a pointer (which it most definitely is), then you don't allocate enough memory. What you should have allocated is `sizeof(node)` instead. The version posted by chux is even better, because it allocates `sizeof("whatever type newlist is pointing to")` which is always correct. This last version is pretty much industry standard, and for a good reason (because it avoids precisely the type of mistake you've made in your code)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you `return newlist;` you will need to pass the address of `list`, e.g. `item pophead(node **list)` so you can operate on the original pointer, instead of a copy. Why? C is pass-by-value, when you pass a variable as a parameter, the function receives a copy of the variable. Any changes you make in your function are lost on return.

To avoid this you can pass the address of the parameter, and while the function will still receive a copy of the pointer, it will contain the original address as its value. You could do:

```
item pophead(node **list)
{
    head = *list;
    // node *newlist = malloc(sizeof *newlist);  // (no allocation needed)
    node *newlist = NULL;
    item result;
    if(!*list)
    {
        perror("There is nothing to be pop\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        newlist = head->next;
        result = head->data;
        free(head);
        *list = newlist;
    }
    return result;
}
```

(**note:** there is no need to allocate for `newlist`, you are simply assigning the address from an existing node to a pointer not copying the content to new storage)

Then in your calling function instead of calling:

```
item someitem = pophead (list);
```

you would call

```
item someitem = pophead (&list);
```

(**note:** In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714))

---

**Returning Nothing or `struct item` Depending Whether List Empty**

From our extended discussion, from what I gleaned from our conversation, you are saying with `item result;` if the list is empty, you would like to return nothing, or otherwise you would like to return `result`.

You have declared your function to return type `item`, and you have confirmed that `item` is type `struct` and not a `typedef` of a *pointer*. The *type* controls what you can return. When you declare your function to return type `item` -- that is what it must return. If the type were `item *`, then you would have the option of returning `NULL` (and empty pointer) or a pointer to an allocated block holding type `item`.

You can return a struct `item` initialized all zero in case the list is empty or a struct fully populated with values in the event the list has nodes. Where you currently declare:

```
    item result;    /* which leaves the values indeterminate */
```

You can initialize using the universal initializer `{0}`, or the preferred initialization in C would be to use a *named initializer* where you can set the value of the first member to zero (or empty-string in the case of a character array) and all other members will be initialized zero by default, e.g.

```
    item result = {0};
```

Returning an `item` initialized zero or returning an `item` with the members filled with values are your only two options for your function with return type `item`. You cannot simply `return;` as you would do with a `void` return type, so you either change the function type or return `result` either initialized all zero or with values.

Comment: I'm sorry but I want to ask whether you understand the problem I have? Because, my problem is in the FIRST CASE, for more detail, it is the ``return;`` i use, not the way I use pointer-to-pointer or pointer in this function. Moreover, I intend to use pointer because I don't want to move my pointer from head to new place.

Comment: If you `free(list)` you have to move it somewhere, otherwise you have just freed the address to the beginning of your list and later attempts to access it will invoke undefined behavior. So long as `item` is a type defined earlier in your code then `return result;` is fine. (the answer presumes `head` is a global defined earlier in your code - if not, let me know and we will work further on the problem.)

Comment: If `item` is a **typedef'ed** pointer -- then no it won't work. You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: Yes, you're right because ``item`` as I have mentioned, is a structure data type I have defined earlier and ``head`` is the pointer I used as a global variable which contains the head address of the list I am using. I want to repeat my problem again which is in the case to check whether the list is empty or not. If it is empty I want to return nothing but, unlike pointer I have NULL, I don't know which one is suitable

Comment: I confirm that my typedef ``item`` as a data type is really fine because except for the case I get trouble, I run my program properly

Comment: `NULL` is a pointer value. So you can `if(!*list)` (or `if(!list)` in your original case) `return NULL;` OR just initialize `item result = NULL`; and then you can `return result;` in either case.

Comment: I really recommend you that you should re-read my source code. How could I return NULL in this case because I am trying to return an ``item`` variable, not return list because I have define my function as ``item``, not ``node*`` (because my list is ``node*``)

Comment: You confirmed `item` is a **typedef** to a pointer. So you are returning a pointer value. If that was not the case, you could not `return result;` at the end. Since it is a pointer, you can return `NULL` or an actual address that will be stored as the value of the pointer the function return is assigned to back in the caller. In order for me to provide a more concise answer, please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't say that item is a pointer data type, where do you find it? I just say that it is a normal structure data type. If it is a pointer structure data type, this question is such a weird one because if I want to return nothing, ``NULL`` is a good choice, nothing to say. But it is just a normal one.

Comment: Also, if you do not want to change the head of your list, you cannot `free(list);`. If you do, the first node in your list is gone-forever. That is why it is important to either pass the address of the `node*` so the change is visible back in the caller, assign `head = newlist;` at the end of your function, or change your return type to `node *` are return `newlist` and assign to `head` back in the caller.

Comment: `"I confirm that my typedef item as a data type"` -- what else is that supposed to mean??

Comment: ``I confirm that my typedef item as a data type is really fine`` is my full sentence, you just read a upper part? I want to say that my data type ``item`` run well, nothing wrong here, just like that

Comment: Okay -- lets say we were miscommunicating and `item` is a `struct` and not a pointer to `struct`. Then change the function type to `item *` and allocate for `result`. If the list is empty or the allocation fails return `NULL` if not, then you can do `*result - head->data;` and `return result;`  ( the problems with `free(list)` remain)

Comment: OK, I have thought about the solution you just gave me but I find it quite manual because  I want to know whether there is a way to return nothing a structure. How about initialize my variable ``result``?

Comment: You can return the empty struct or you can return the filled struct, but if your function return is type `item` that is what you are returning. If it is a `struct` it cannot be `NULL`. It can be initialized all zero with `item result = {0};` (or use a named intiializer). (note: I'm going to go ahead and delete this answer -- since it focused on your handling of the list to begin with and secondarily with the return of the struct) In order to ensure others do not have the same difficulty, please provide the MCVE so we can see what `item` is, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You must first decide your precondition.  Will you require that the list be non-empty, or do you handle an empty list?  Given the precondition that the list is non-empty, you can return the item by value without the need for an error indicator.  If the list can be empty, then you will need to return either an error or an item.

If you return a pointer to the head `node`, then you make the caller responsible for freeing the `node`.  If you return the `item` within the head `node`, then you will have to worry about freeing the `node`.

You will also need a way to modify the caller's view of the list.  You are currently passing the list by value, so your changes to the `list` variable will not be visible to the caller.  You will need to pass the list by reference.

I'm going to assume you want to return the `item`, and that the `node` can be freed with `free`.  In this case, we can return a `0` for success and a `-1` for failure, pass the list by reference, and also pass a pointer to where you want the popped `item` (if any) to be placed.

```
int pophead(node **list, item *item)
{
    node *head = *list; // get a pointer to the head node

    if (head == NULL) {
        return -1; // list is empty; error
    }

    *item = head->data; // copy the data to the output
    *list = head->next; // update the list
    free(head);         // free the head element

    return 0; // success
}
```

You would then call the function like so:

```
node *the_list = NULL;

// TODO: populate the_list somehow

item the_item;

if (pophead(&the_list, &the_item) == 0) {
    // process the_item
}
```

By the way, in C++, the Standard Template Library defines the precondition that list be non-empty so that popping cannot fail.  It provides a separate function to test if the list is non-empty, which the caller must check before attempting to pop.  In this way, the item can be returned by value without needing to return an error indicator.

In C, it is not generally possible to return something that can have any value or error.